# PDFLatex: Unable to Generate Index

Tags: pdftex, indexing

Master file:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{book}

% File Containing All the Control Settings
\usepackage{../../Style/mystyle}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

% Front Cover
\include {Front_Cover/frontcover}


% Chapters
\include {Chapters/CH_Analysis_of_Algorithms/Analysis_of_Algorithms}
\include {Chapters/CH_Abstract_Data_Types/Abstract_Data_Types}
\include {Chapters/CH_Arrays/Arrays}
\include {Chapters/CH_Linked_Lists/Linked_Lists}
\include {Chapters/CH_Stacks/Stacks}
\include  {Bibliography/biblio}

% Index
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I compiled it as follows:

```
$pdflatex master.tex
```

=> Empty `idx` file generated

```
$makeindex master.idx
```

**This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2012] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file master.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in master.ind.
Transcript written in master.ilg.**

```
$pdflatex master.tex
```

Output: PDF with NO Index.

I am compiling from the command line using `pdflatex` (don't use `latex` to avoid boxing issues with graphics)

Please guide me on this issue.

Comment: The file you have provided here cannot compile as is: `\printindex` will make `pdflatex` choke.  I assume you have something in your `mystyle.sty` file that allows you to compile your document. Also, why are you calling `makeindex master.idx` and yet `makeindex` is scanning `control.idx` for index entries (and, clearly finding none!)?  Finally, are the `dvipsnames` and `cmyk` options mentioned when you are not using them?  Minimal working examples are always valuable, but they can't be too minimal.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- You mean `makeindex master.idx` (or just `master` without an explicit extension)?

Comment: The command I fired was: makeindex master.idx. Should I drop '.idx' extension here?

Comment: @Harish Kumar: The style file is too large to share here. It is the part of my ongoing Book Project.

Comment: Then you should boil down to a MWE and only share that. This is a classic debug technique and could also help you find the mistake yourself.

Comment: @Harish: Sorry, I forgot to edit the Error Message. The actual name was 'control.tex', but since it sounds somewhat weird, I renamed it to master.tex while posting.

Comment: Do you have `\index` commands at all? Without `\index` the `.idx` file would remain empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Just to end this thing:)
In your given MWE were two problems:

1. I can't see that you loads package `makeidx`. It seems you load it in `mystyle.sty` (your cited message tells this).
2. As Heiko mentioned you have no macros `\index{...}` in your MWE.

A real working MWE for your case would look like this:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68538/pdflatex-unable-to-generate-index
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}   % load package
\makeindex             % make file(s) *.idx

\begin{document}
Test\index{Test} Text\index{Text|textbf}

\printindex            % print index here
\end{document}
```

with the result, that everything is working now. Building such a MWE by your own helps you a lot to learn how TeX/LaTeX is working. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I was confused by the term 'automatic index generation'. I was expecting some dictionary generation. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

when invoking `makeindex` from TexnicCenter I had the same error message. It screened `mydocument.idx` which was an empty file created when running LaTeX and subsequently found no entries and produced no output. I found the nomenclatures in `mydocument.nlo` where they are supposed to be. So `makeindex` just took the wrong input file and consequently produced no output because it was empty.

So you have to invoke `makeindex` on your own via the command window in windows (cmd). You have to go in the directory where your document lies (with `cd` ...) Then just run

```
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
```

And indeed `makeindex` makes the output file `mydocuemnt.nls`.

When you run LaTeX again it will find `mydocument.nls` and produce the nomenclature list.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).